# How can I loop do while with Apache Camel

Tags: while-loop, apache-camel

I'm having problems with the loopDoWhile pattern in my camel route.
Note that without the loopDoWhile the route works fine and returns a set of items to the "classe 1" route.

classe 1 :

```
from(LISTE_URI)
.process(listRequestProcessor)
.to("direct:netty4-tcp-route")
.process(listResponseProcessor);
```

classe 2 :

```
from("direct:netty4-tcp-route")
.loopDoWhile(exchangeProperty("endOfList").isNotEqualTo("true"))
.marshal(myDataFormat)
.to(netty4URI)
.unmarshal(myDataFormat);
```

The server I'm calling returns a partial list of items and a "endOfList" set to true or false depending on there are more items to fetch.
I then need to recall the server until endOfList is true.

With the "loopDoWhile" pattern I'm looping and my final list is growing as expected **BUT** the list is not returned to the classe 1 route at the end of the looping. No response from the classe 2 route (while I have one without looping).

Answer (score 1):

After a while searching the wrong direction, it appears the problem was due to the netty call : I had to use enrich(netty4URI) instead of to(netty4URI).

Answer (score 0):

The doWhile loop in camel can be written in the below ways :

Way 1 (Simple) --> String Predicate :

```
from("direct:simple")
  .loopDoWhile(simple("${body.length} <= 5"))
  .to("mock:loop")
  .transform(body().append("A"))
  .end()
  .to("mock:result");
```

Way 2 (functional) --> String Predicate :

```
 from("direct:functional")
  .loopDoWhile()
  .body(String.class, b -> b.length() <= 5)
  .to("mock:loop")
  .transform()
  .body(String.class, b -> b += "A")
  .end()
  .to("mock:result");
```

Way 2 (functional) --> Boolean Predicate :

```
 boolean flag = true;
 from("direct:functional")
  .loopDoWhile()
  .body(Boolean.class, b -> flag == false)
  .to("mock:loop")
  .end()
  .to("mock:result");
```

You can use the above cases to fit your use case.